# Django not like statement

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

how to use not like in django queries

```
    Model.objects.filter(keywords not like "null" or "undefined")

       select * from model where keywords not like "%undefined%"  or keywords not like "%null%";
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use the `exclude` function and `Q` objects

```
Model.objects.exclude(Q(keyword__contains='undefined') | Q(keyword__contains='null'))
```