# "Not like" condition in QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

New to Django, and below is my issue :

**Background**

I have a column having values like :

```
ABCDEF
ABCDDD
ABCDEG
ACDFER
ACDFDF
AVXZSE
XSDFRW
```

and i want to reject values starting from `AV` and `XS`, i am really surprised i am not getting anything online related to django query set which can help me do this as against `MySQL`'s simple `not like "AV%"`.
One solution [i found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193097/django-not-like-statement) is related to `Q`, but i am not at liberty to use any thing *out-of-native-inbuilt* methods.

**Problem :**

I was wondering if someone can guide me to execute `exclude` for above scenario, something like this :

```
DataSet.exclude(column_name="^AV",column_name="^XS")
```

Comment: "One solution i found on SO is related to Q, but i am not at liberty to use any thing out-of-native-inbuilt methods." that makes no sense, `Q` objects are a built-in part of Django

Comment: i'll admit my knowledge is still pretty low to identify *built-in*s against the non ones....i made the quoted assumption when i got this error => `NameError: name 'Q' is not defined`

Comment: ah, that just means you haven't imported it into your python file, you need a line like `from django.db.models import Q` at the top with your other imports

Comment: damnnnn.....now you know why i have screen name like what i have!! :D

Comment: no prob, we all have to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`__startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-startswith) is what you want.

```
DataSet.exclude(column_name__startswith="AV").exclude(column_name__startswith="XS")
```

(Note I don't understand your objection to Q: none of Django is built-in, and Q is exactly as much a part of core Django as any QuerySet method.)

Comment: i tried working with `Q` but shell was throwing error with it....and new in the project i kind of got scared!! :)
Out of curiosity, with 2 `exclude`, does django first fetches dataset *not having* `AV` and then again re-scans this dataset to remove `XS`....so 2 scans overall?

Comment: @NoobEditor no, Django does nothing until you try to access elements from the queryset, at that point it does a single query _[querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)_